# python-docx is reading document as blank

Tags: python, reporting-services, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to read a docx file that was exported from Microsoft Report Builder:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document(file_name)
tables = doc.tables
print(len(tables))
for a in tables:
    print(len(a.rows))
    for r in a.rows:
        for c in r.cells:
            for p in c.paragraphs:
                if p.text is not None:
                    print(p.text)
```

The code throws no errors at any level. It shows a table object that contains 22 rows, each containing 3 cells, containing paragraphs and text, etc. All of these objects are blank. Any ideas why everything is blank? I am thinking it has something to do with the way that Report Builder encodes its output.

Comment: Best bet is to inspect the XML of the `document.xml` part (have to unzip the .docx first). If the paragraphs or runs inside each cell are "wrapped" in some "container" element like a field or content control, this is the behavior you would get. A simpler start would be to extend your print statements to count the cells and paragraphs (and add runs), and see where zero first shows up. But I'm betting on a wrapper, assuming anything shows up when you open it in Word.

Comment: As @scanny suggested, when SSRS renders to word is embeds tables and cells within outer tables and cells. I think it does this to try to maintain the visual layout of the original report design. I wrote an entire application to strip out and clean up this mess but that was for a very specific task so it would not be useful for you.